# Best cross-platform technology (IPhone, Android) to use for mapping application

Tags: android, iphone, cross-platform

I am building an application in which users can search for specific locations on a map. I am looking to use cross-platform technology as minimizing development time is incredibly important. At the moment I have looked at Ionic and React-native, which both have mapping functionalities, however, neither shows any clear advantages from my research. If development time is the most important factor in development (I have 3 weeks), what is the best cross-platform technology to use?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend flutter.
https://flutter.dev/

They just been released last year, December 4th, 2018 but Google have made a continuous improvement time to time.

Check it out it might help you out.

Answer (score 0):

For the quickest development you should try Expo (https://expo.io/). You will be writing React Native but the hard parts have been simplified for you.

And you can easily use maps https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/map-view/.

Comment: Are there any drawbacks vs React-Native

Comment: It is React Native, but you can see a great explanation about differences if you want to do React Native without expo. The analogy is that Expo is what Rails does with Ruby.